# java.io.FileNotFoundException:retrieve a set of files from a folder in server

Tags: java, client, download

I'm attempting to fetch a set of files from server, using `getfile()`, and I get this Exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\SERVER\Server Content\Apps\icons (Access is denied)

Here's my code:

```
DownloadController downloadcontroller = null;
try {
    downloadcontroller = ServerConnector.getServerConnector().getDownloadController();
} catch (NotBoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(HomeUI_2Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(HomeUI_2Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (RemoteException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(HomeUI_2Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

RemoteInputStream file = null;
try {
    file = downloadcontroller.getFile("E:\\SERVER\\Server Content\\Apps\\icons");
} catch (IOException ex) {}

public RemoteInputStream getFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    // create a RemoteStreamServer (note the finally block which only releases
    // the RMI resources if the method fails before returning.)

    //read data
    RemoteInputStreamServer istream = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                fileInputStream);
        istream = new SimpleRemoteInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
        // export the final stream for returning to the client

        //send data
        RemoteInputStream result = istream.export();
        // after all the hard work, discard the local reference (we are passing
        // responsibility to the client)
        istream = null;
        return result;
    } finally {
        // we will only close the stream here if the server fails before
        // returning an exported stream
        if (istream != null) {
            istream.close();
        }
    }
}

Logger.getLogger(HomeUI_2Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward. You don't have rights to that folder/file.

Comment: That not depends on your code.the user that runs the code have no permissions to read the files or directories.

Comment: @Jens Well I've adjusted folder permissions.But still no effect

Comment: Of all folder in the hierarchy and all files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot open and read a directory, use the isFile() and isDirectory() methods to distinguish between files and folders. 
You can get the contents of folders using the list() and listFiles() methods (for filenames and Files respectively) you can also specify a filter that selects a subset of files listed.